# Не выдает результат в новом потоке

Tags: android, многопоточность

В этом классе генерируется List, и должен выводиться в Log, но этого не происходит, хотя поток создается

```
private class LooperThread extends Thread implements Handler.Callback{

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler(this);
        Looper.loop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        if(message.what == 0){
            DepositGeneration generation = new DepositGeneration();
            DepositOperations operations = new DepositOperations(generation.setList());
            List<DepositItem> list = operations.sortedList();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("TAG", list.get(i).getName() +
                        " " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(list.get(i).getOpenedDate()) +
                        " " + new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(list.get(i).getAmount()));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }
}
```

И его вызов

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    looperThread = new LooperThread();
    looperThread.start();


}
```

В конце уничтожаю поток

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(looperThread.getHandler() != null){
        Log.d("TAG", "DESTROY");
        looperThread.getHandler().getLooper().quit();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Сообщение в Log, что уничтожено, выходит

Изменил вызов и передаю сообщение, но не выполняется

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    looperThread = new LooperThread();

    if (looperThread.getHandler() != null){
        Message message = looperThread.getHandler().obtainMessage(0);
        message.sendToTarget();
    }

    looperThread.start();

}
```

Comment: Вы ждёте, что отработает колбек хандлера, но я не вижу, чтобы Вы посылали ему сообщение. Вообще не понятно зачем Вы использовали `LooperThread`, а не просто `Thread`.

Comment: Проверить, как работает, он же должен и без сообщения выполнить?

Comment: Нет не должен. Должен выполниться `run`, а `handleMessage` не принадлежит `LooperThread` и никак с ним не связан. Он вызывается хендлером при получении сообщения, вернее когда сообщение должно быть обработано.

Comment: @woesss, изменил, передаю сообщение, его и проверяю в handlerMessage(), но также не выполняется, ошибка на null выходит

Comment: Вы инициализируете хэндлер в `run`, который сработает после вызова `looperThread.start();` и то не факт, что моментально. А Вы и вовсе до старта к нему обращаетесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил, отправляю сообщение в oncreateView

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    if (looperThread.getHandler() != null){
        Message message = looperThread.getHandler().obtainMessage(0);
        message.sendToTarget();
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Будет проще и лучше использовать асинхронный запрос.

**Делается он таким образом:**

```
class AsyncTaskTest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//Тут код перед выполнением вашей задачи. Метод имеет доступ к UI.
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Тут код для выполнения вашей задачи. Метод не имеет доступ к UI.
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
//Тут код после выполнением вашей задачи. Метод имеет доступ к UI.
        }
    }
```

**Вызывается вот так:**

```
AsyncTaskTest asyncTaskTest = new AsyncTaskTest();
    asyncTaskTest.execute();
```

Вот и все. И не нужно мучиться. :)

Comment: Мне не нужен пока AsynsTask

Answer (score 1):

`handleMessage` принадлежит `Handler.Callback` и вызывается классом `Handler`, когда он получил сообщение и настало время его выполнить.
`Thread` ничего не знает об этом методе и не выполняет его самопроизвольно.

Comment: Тогда как можно исправить код?

Comment: Как минимум обращаться к `Handler` после вызова `looperThread.start();`, а ещё лучше в другом методе, выполняющемся позже.